# Build failed with an exception [Android SDK Platform 25]

Tags: android, node.js, git, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to run the command ionic build android --release to build the apk but i am getting this error

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.623 secs
>   Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>     You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>     [Android SDK Platform 25].
>     Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
>     Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[image]

Someone help me please and Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: In the above logs it's clearly said that while installing the SDK , you didn't accept the license agreement.

Comment: @Muhammad Install android SDk version 25 and accept license during installation

Comment: So, what should I do ? @Danger

Comment: You have to uninstall the studio and install again, and when it asks for license agreement, select I agree, and then go next.

Comment: what do you means , uninstall Android Studio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you accept the license agreement during installation? If not, uninstall and then re-install and this time accept the license agreement.

Comment: Hi dude, what is in uninstall, ? i'm not understand please,

Comment: Mean remove Android SDK completely and then re-install it.

Comment: **SOLDVED**  when I install Android SDK  Platform 25 from SDK Manager